# function on $scope vs function on $window

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, window

We can create functions at `scope` level. If i have a controller `todoCtrl` then if i define a function inside the controller `scope` that method will reside inside the controller scope.

For example,

```
$scope.scopeMet = function() {}
```

We can also define methods at window level using $window service of angular.

For example,

```
$window.onSignIn = function() {}
```

Google Sign in callback is captured at window level, hence, i was curious to know what is the meaning and the difference between the two illustrations given above ?

Comment: You would only ever used the second if there was some external library that needed global level access, which is quite rare. For all other parts of an angular app you keep things inside angular context